# Vaadin Icon Alignment

Tags: java, icons, vaadin

I Want to Align my icon in Center of Layout but I guess I am  missing something Please refer  me appropriate answer.

java code

```
Image image1 = new Image("icons/Pic1.png", "My Alt Image");
image1.setWidth("40px");
image1.setHeight("40px");
image1.getStyle().set("text-Align", "CENTER");'
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put this image? You have to add text-align to the component where you add the icon.

For example

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center"><p>Hello</p></div>
```

or with vaadin

```
Div div = new Div();
div.getStyle().set("text-align", "center");

Image image1 = new Image("icons/Pic1.png", "My Alt Image");
image1.setWidth("40px");
image1.setHeight("40px");
div.add(image1);
```

If using a HorizontalLayout this would be like this

```
HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
Image image1 = new Image("icons/Pic1.png", "My Alt Image");
image1.setWidth("40px");
image1.setHeight("40px");
layout.add(image1);

layout.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
```

Read more about Vaadin layouts: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/basic-layouts/#horizontal-layout

Comment: i am adding this image on horizontal layout

Comment: See my updated answer